# PHP Class Import

Tags: php

Here's a sample code that I'm trying to call from another page to help me with stats. I can't seem to get it to work. How do I import and call this class in another php file? `stats.php`

```
<?php

include("config.php");
$link = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db("mydb", $link);

class stats{

  function newReg(){

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people where status ='registered' ", $link);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
     return $num_rows ;


function newApp(){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people where status = 'NEW' ", $link);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    return $num_rows;
 }
?>
```

I want to call that class here in another file:

```
<?php

require_once("stats.php");
   echo(stats.newReg());

 ?>
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Without seeing the code where you try to include it in the other page, it's difficult to help...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you forgot 2 closing brackets

```
<?php

include("config.php");
$link = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db("mydb", $link);

class stats{

  function newReg(){
    global $link;
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people where status ='registered' ", $link);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
     return $num_rows ;
  }

function newApp(){
    global $link;        
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people where status = 'NEW' ", $link);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    return $num_rows;
 }
}
?>
```

anyway, other file:

```
include 'statsclassfile.php';
$myStats = new stats();
$mystats->newReg();
```

PS: naming conventions generally want that class names begin with a capital letter, eg: `Stats`

Comment: thanks for your comment. But I'm getting <i>Fatal error: Call to a member function newReg() on a non-object in /home/default/helen/testStats.php on line 4</i>

Comment: put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of the file testStats.php and see if the script reports more details on why it doesn't instance your class.

One question, are the 3 files (config.php, testStats.php and the other one) all in the same directory?

Comment: actually... `$link` is declared in global space. That means you cannot access it from within a function without declaring it there as global. I'll update my answer to include this change. (this has nothing to do with the include problem)

Comment: Thanks again for your amazing help. It's now working like a dream. You've been very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the paths are correct, maybe the config.php file is not on the same folder.

You can use absolute paths like this

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/path_to_config/config.php";
```

And to call your stats class:

```
require_once PATH_TO_YOUR_CLASS . "stats.php"
```

Also make sure you name classes with CamelCased names.

Comment: It's actually `PascalCase`, not `camelCase`. ;)