# Importing a php file

Tags: php

I have two PHP files. 
The first:

```
<?php
use App\Router as Route;
include "routes.php";
...
```

The second 'routes.php' file:

```
<?php
Route::get('/', 'function(){echo "homepage";}');
...
```

But when I run it I get an error. I have to add:
`use App\Route as Route` for the Routes.php file to work.

Is there a way to include `routes.php` into the first PHP file without adding `use App\Route as Route` at the top of the file since its being included in the first file that is importing it?
I'm using PHP7.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Class Import](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929723/php-class-import)

Comment: This is the namespace issue, check namespace in both files

Comment: The first file is namespaced. the second isnt. why do i have to namespace the second file for it to run. shouldnt importing the second file already be in scope since it is being imported in an already namespaced file???

Comment: Namespaces are per file.

Comment: OK thanks Charlotte.